# Combining Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to eliminate the below temporary Map and combine it into one `Stream`. I tried a little here and there, but came up with no solution. So there is no code what I can present so far, since my approaches would probably be misleading.

```
final Map<String, String> tempCountryMap = iso3166Alpha2CountryCodes.stream() //
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(cc -> cc, cc -> new Locale("", cc).getDisplayCountry(locale)));

final Map<String, String> sortedMap = tempCountryMap.entrySet().stream() //
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collator.getInstance(locale))) //
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry<String, String>::getKey, Entry<String, String>::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
      LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Have you tried Stream.concat()?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single pipeline if you map the elements of the original `Stream` to `Map.Entry`s and then proceed with the sorting:

```
final Map<String, String> sortedMap = 
    iso3166Alpha2CountryCodes.stream()
                             .map(cc -> new SimpleEntry<>(cc,new Locale("", cc).getDisplayCountry(locale)))
                             .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collator.getInstance(locale)))
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                                       Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                                       (e1, e2) -> e2,
                                                       LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Would have never come up with this solution. Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @user871611 it's often useful to map elements of a Stream into pairs of other elements, so  `SimpleEntry`, which implements `Map.Entry`, comes handy in many scenarios.